# Possible approaches to dealing with unbalanced dataset and highly biased deep learning algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, algorithmic-bias

I have an extremely unbalanced  video dataset  for a two class video classification problem.All my videos in my current video dataset is $40$ second long with $900p$ resolution.However the dataset is highly unbalanced with $3000$ samples for class A vs $300$ samples to class B. Due to high imbalance, i added the following class weight implementation to my deep learning model.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html

However  my model was still heavily biased due to high imbalance in data. I am considering   the following options:

- Adding more video data to balance the dataset:  My only concern here is my current dataset is uniform with same duration of videos and similar resolution of around $900p$. Will it matter if I add  very low resolution videos to balance the dataset?
- Adding video augmentation to current dataset.

I am looking for any other recommendations that i could make use. Any pros or cons of any of these methods that I should consider to prevent any bias?

Comment: Welcome to AI.SE. Just a few clarifications. What do you mean by 'biased' here?